# Is it possible to develop for Android on Android?

Tags: java, android, mobile, ssh

Lately I've been doing a lot of web development on my Droid via ssh using the ConnectBot app and a few other apps for reference.  I've also been doing a lot of Android development back home in eclipse, and I wondered: would it be possible to develop and test my android projects right on my phone?  All I can do at the moment is either write the code via ssh and then open it later with eclipse to finish it up, or remotely use eclipse via LogMeIn Ignition or VNC.  Does anyone know a native way to do what I'm trying to do, preferably offline?

Comment: You are writing code with the android keyboard?

Comment: lots of phones have real keyboards now!

Answer (score 5):

Try AIDE. I use it because it supports Eclipse projects. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this hits the target you're looking for, but [The Scripting Layer for Android](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) (formerly known as the Android Scripting Environment) is available and has a lot of power available to it.

> Scripting Layer for Android (SL4A,
>   formerly known as Android Scripting
>   Environment or ASE) brings scripting
>   languages to Android by allowing you
>   to edit and execute scripts and
>   interactive interpreters directly on
>   the Android device. These scripts have
>   access to many of the APIs available
>   to full-fledged Android applications,
>   but with a greatly simplified
>   interface that makes it easy to get
>   things done.
>
> Scripts can be run interactively in a
>   terminal, in the background, or via
>   [Locale](http://www.androidlocale.com/). Python, Perl, JRuby, Lua,
>   BeanShell, JavaScript, Tcl, and shell
>   are currently supported, and we're
>   planning to add more. See the [SL4A
>   Video Help playlist](http://www.youtube.com/user/damonkohler#g/c/07A81E6CE96F158B) on YouTube for
>   various demonstrations of SL4A's
>   features.

Answer (score 1):

I found DroidScript. It's a quite powerful JavaScript interpreter thats based on the Rhino-library. It can import every Java-package and even create activities for starting from the launcher. The URL is http://droidscript.se for the Live-Editor with which you can edit scripts online and send them to your phone, and the droidscript-app has an editor, too but it cant save at the moment, i think. DroidScript is Open-Source and embeddable in an own app, I think. More info on news of DroidScript are found on droidscript.blogspot.com.

Answer (score 1):

check out [JAVAIDEDROID](http://code.google.com/p/java-ide-droid/) on the market

Answer (score 1):

You can if you have a remote linux machine that you normaly develop on.

1. ssh into the machine with some ssh app.
2. edit the code with some console text editor (vim for example).
3. build the application with ant
4. copy the generated apk into the android phone and install it
5. repeat from point 2.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know if it's possible, but to do it, you should:

- "Install" java inside Android.
- "Install" ant
- run `ant debug`

Check [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/other-ide.html#Building) for more instructions.

PS: Please let us know if you could do it :)

Comment: As I understand it, Android doesn't run Java directly, it compiles it to an executable format.  I'm guessing actually installing Java on your phone would be problematic (If not, I'm trading in my iPhone!)

Comment: You should be able to compile the Ant sources to the Android  bytecode format. But I have no idea how you'd make javac run on Android, since that's a native program.